# Minimum number of splits graph into two sets to delete all edges.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, constructive-mathematics

You are given a graph with $N$ vertices and $M$ edges. For one operation you can divide vertex set into two sets. After each operation you delete all edges between vertices from different sets. 
The question is the minimum number of operation to do so and find this operations.

For complete graph the answer is $\lceil{\log_2N}\rceil$. We can do it like this:
put odd vertices into first set, even - to the second, after that do the same for odd and even sets and so on...

Comment: You didn't say what you mean by "divide graph into two sets" but I'm guessing that you mean "divide the **vertex set** into two sets".

Comment: fixed, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The minimum numnber of splits is $\left\lceil\log_2\chi(G)\right\rceil$ where $\chi(G)$ is the [chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring) of the graph $G$. In other words, $m$ splits suffice if and only if $G$ is $2^m$-colorable.

**Explanation.** A set of vertices is *independent* if no two vertices in the set are joined by an edge. A graph is $n$-*colorable* if the set of vertices can be partitioned into $n$ (or fewer) independent sets; the *chromatic number* $\chi(G)$ is the smallest $n$ such that $G$ is $n$-colorable.

Suppose $\chi(G)=n$. Consider a partition of the vertex set $V$ into independent sets $V_1,V_2,\dots,V_n$. In the special case where $G$ is a complete graph $K_n$, the sets $V_i$ consist of one vertex each, $V_i=\{v_i\}$. You already know how to destroy all the edges of $K_n$ with $\left\lceil\log_2n\right\rceil$ splits. Essentially the same method works for $G$, with the sets $V_i$ playing the role of vertices. At the first step, you put $V_1\cup V_3\cup V_5\cup\cdots$ into one set, $V_2\cup V_4\cup V_y\cup\cdots$ into the other. And so forth.

Comment: Please, tell me how to find such splits?

Comment: @sandorik The same way you did it for the complete graph?

Comment: Suppose $G$ is $2^m$-colorable. The color of a vertex $v$ is a string $(c_1(v),c_2(v),\dots,c_m(v))$ where $c_i(v)\in\{0,1\}$. For the $i^{\text{th}}$ split, split the vertices according to the value of $c_i(v)$.

Comment: But what if we have two vertices connected with edge with same string? Or you mean that we color our graph in $2^m$ colors, and after that transform every color from decimal to binary?
Also, how you can proof this solution?

Comment: If two vertices are colored with the same string, then ther can be no edge between them. When we say $G$ is $2^m$-colorable, that means it admits a **proper** coloring of vertices with $2^m$ colors, i.e., if two vertices are joined by an edge then they must get different colors (different strings).

Comment: @sandorik I added an explanation to my answer.